# Triangles from n points

Tags: combinatorics

There are 100 different points on the plane. How many triangles can be made from these points?
I think, the right answer is $100!/97!$ , my friend thinks is $1.617*(10^5)$ , Who's right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the points are in general position, you are choosing three points out of 100, where order doesn't matter. There are 
$$\binom{100}{3} = \frac{100!}{97!3!} = 161700$$
ways of doing this.

So your friend is right, though as a matter of style I would not use scientific notation to represent an exact integer.

Comment: What if the points are collinear?

Comment: @user222031 Yeah, surely the points are either assumed to be in general position, or degenerate triangles with different vertex positions are considered distinct, since otherwise there's no way to answer the question.